# PHP Imagick not working with php 7.2.6

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, php-7.2

I have recently loaded php 7.2.6 on my windows server and I have installed the php Imagick extension. The extension is installed properly and it shows up in the phpinfo, but when I run the application, it keeps throwing me the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   imagick_readimage()

My php ini information is as follows:

[Php Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCLR8.png)

Could someone help me and let me know what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't a function called `imagick_readimage()`. It is called `Imagick::readImage()` http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php

Comment: This helped but I have been using this implementation in php5.6 and it was working properly is there any change in imagick for php  7.2

Comment: Did you install ImageMagick 6 or ImageMagick 7? If the latter, then perhaps Imagick is not compatible with IM 7?

Comment: I downloaded this package of Imagick php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-nts-vc14-x86 where can I get ImageMagick 6 from

Comment: You have not said what platform you are on. All ImageMagick binaries are at https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/download.php for version 6 and at https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php for version 7. But you should check with the Imagick version as to which ImageMagick version that it needs.

Comment: I got the issue fixed thanks for your hep